# Alignment problem with systeme

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, systeme

I have a problem with latex. I use `\systeme`and
I have this :

[image]

And I would like to have this :

[image]

With the Latex Code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\systeme{3x-3= 0, 2x-3y+6=0}
\\
\\

\systeme*{3x-3= 0, 2x-3y+6=0}

\end{document}
```

Do you know how to do with `\systeme` to delete alignement ?
Thank you for reading this message and for your reponses

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't think it's possible, but why don't you simply use a `cases` environment?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibilities beside mentioned in @Bernard comment, is use the `empheq` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
& 3x-3= 0,  \\
&2x-3y+6=0
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `systeme`, but with some “local” settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysalign{l,l} % left alignment
\def\eq{=} % mask the =
\systeme*{5y \eq 0, 2x+3y-5 \eq 0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took what egreg gave me, but it doesn't work 
I have this in the message error :

! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \sysalign
{l,l}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

It doesn't know the l,l in the sys align...

Do someone know why ? And how I can fix it ?

Comment: @Mathilde You possibly have an outdated version of the TeX system

Comment: Hello, I've made update of TeX, and it's still doesn't work.. I still have the same message... @egreg

Comment: @Mathilde `\sysalign` is available only with `systeme` version 0.34 released 2020/05/03, so you need TeX Live 2020.